How to allow direct connection to plex media server
im trying to set up plex media server on ubuntu server os.
i installed the plex media server and when im trying to watch in the same network everything is ok.
the problem starts when i try to stream outside of my home network. for example, my father who lives in another city is trying to watch a movie. the quality is very bad.
the movie is transcoded to 320p and not playing in the original quality (1080p).
original quality is not even showed as an option.
i thinks it has something to do with a message that popped up saying that the connection to the server is indirect.
i tried to create a rule in the ufw.
i created a file called plexmediaserver in the /etc/ufw/applications.d/ directory and inserted this text:
[plexmediaserver]
title=Plex Media Server (Standard)
description=The Plex Media Server
ports=32400/tcp

[plexmediaserver-additional]
title=Plex Media Server (Additional)
description=The Plex Media Server (Additional Ports)
ports=5353/udp|8324/tcp|32410:32414/udp|1900/udp|32469/tcp

i saved the file and executed the following commands:

sudo ufw app update plexmediaserver


sudo ufw allow plexmediaserver

it didn't solve the problem.
my question is, how do i make the connection direct so i can watch in the original quality outside my home network.
thanks in advance.
